# Azure Table: What is the best performance to store guid in Azure Table?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I want store just one value in row: guid. But I have to set pair: PartitionKey and RowKey, so my pair is:
"guidValue", some_guid
What should be a PartitionKey: guid or const string?

So the structure should be looks like that:

```
PartitionKey: "guidValue"
RowKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E36D

PartitionKey: "guidValue"
RowKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E37D

PartitionKey: "guidValue"
RowKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E38D
```

...

or like that:

```
PartitionKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E36D
RowKey: "guidValue"

PartitionKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E37D
RowKey: "guidValue"

PartitionKey: 951FE9AE-50FA-48F6-96C8-81D10271E38D
RowKey: "guidValue"
```

?

My scenario is: I save guid once and read many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your reading scenario? Listing all existing GUIDs? Or checking the existence of one GUID? Do you want to write multiple GUIDs via one request to save the transaction cost from writing and make writing performance better?

The first option will enable you use EntityGroupTransaction to insert GUIDs in batch, but a table with only one partition key can't be load-balanced to multiple service in Azure Storage back-end. If you'd like to insert GUIDs in batch and the total GUID count is not too many, I'd suggest you to choose option 1; otherwise, option 2 is better.

Comment: My scenario is: detecting duplicate.guid. 
One service will save one by one guid to table. Other service will check if that guid exists in table

Comment: If so, option 2 is the right choice for you since you don't need batch operation.

Answer (score 1):

`PartitionKey` effects load balancing and scalability for each of the storage services.

As the description of table entities at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/#partitions-in-azure-storage:

> The partition key for an entity is account name + table name + partition key, where the partition key is the value of the required user-defined PartitionKey property for the entity. All entities with the same partition key value are grouped into the same partition and are served by the same partition server. This is an important point to understand in designing your application. Your application should balance the scalability benefits of spreading entities across multiple partitions with the data access advantages of grouping entities in a single partition.

And additionally,

> if you wish to perform batch operations on a group of entities, consider grouping them with the same partition key.

For scalability and performance targets and, I suggest you to use your first structure.